# telerik grid show data depending on a condition using server binding

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have a telerik grid, I want to display data as below

```
ProductName Count
Letters     5
Phone   
Pens        3
```

I want to do something like if count>0 then only show th evalue for count column, i.e. do not display value 0.

```
<% Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.Orders)
             .Name("Grid")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(o => o.ProductName);
   if(Count>0)
       {
                columns.Bound(o => o.Count);
       }    
              })
            .Groupable(settings => settings.Groups(groups => groups.Add(o => o.KeyID)).Visible(false))
            .Scrollable(s => s.Enabled(true))
            .Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Height(300))
            .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
            .Footer(true)
            .Render();
        %>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CellAction to render conditional results.

```
<%
Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.Orders)
.Name("Grid")
.CellAction(cell => 
  {
    if (cell.Column.Title.Equals("Count"))
    {
      if (cell.DataItem.Count == 0)
      {
        cell.Text = "&nbsp;";
      }
    }
  })
 .Columns(columns =>
  {
      columns.Bound(o => o.ProductName);
      columns.Bound(o => o.Count);
  })
.Groupable(settings => settings.Groups(groups => groups.Add(o => o.KeyID)).Visible(false))
.Scrollable(s => s.Enabled(true))
.Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Height(300))
.Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
.Footer(true)
%>
```

Comment: Actually it only works for server binding. I just edited the answer. I mistakenly had > 0 instead of == 0.

Comment: Also, I guess there has to be something in the quotes like "&nbsp;". See edit.